# Windows 10 UWP AppService Communication

Tags: c#, uwp

I have several features I for which I am considering AppService.  My concern is the data passed between the service and the applications is information I do not want exposed.

How safe is it to pass sensitive data using AppService?  How does AppService communicate?  Some type of protected memory?  Networking?